# Setting up relationship so users can follow multiple model types through same table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, polymorphism, laravel-5.5, polymorphic-associations

I've been banging my head against my keyboard for about 2 hours now trying to figure this out and I'm finally at a point where I just need help.

[image]

I'm looking to have `Users` be able to follow `Alpha` and `Beta` models through a `Follows` table.

Ideally so that the code could look like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$alpha = Alpha::find(1);
$beta = Beta::find(1);
$user->following()->save($alpha);
$user->following()->save($beta);
```

I've tried this with regular polymorphic relationships and many-to-many polymorphic relationships with varying degrees of success. I haven't been able to fully realize it no matter what I've tried and I think it's just mental exhaustion holding me back at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a one-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Follows` then a traditional polymorphic relationship between `Follows` and `Alphas`/`Betas`.

**Table Structure**

```
alphas
    id - integer
    name - string

betas
    id - integer
    name - string

follows
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    followable_id - integer
    followable_type - string

users
    id - integer
```

**Models**

```
class Follow extends Model
{
    public function followable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class Alpha extends Model
{
    public function follows()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Follow::class, 'followable');
    }
}

class Beta extends Model
{
    public function follows()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Follow::class, 'followable');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function follows()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Follow::class);
    }

    public function alphas()
    {
        return $this->follows()->where('followable_type', Alpha::class);
    }

    public function betas()
    {
        return $this->follows()->where('followable_type', Beta::class);
    }
}
```

**Saving A Relation**

```
$user = User::find($uid);

$follow = new Follow([
    'user_id' => $user->id
]);

$alpha = Alpha::find($aid);

$alpha->follows()->save($follow);
```

Comment: Sigh, you're right. Now if only someone could delete the question to save me the embarrassment. Thanks though, I was definitely over-thinking it.